# OpenCV is not reading the image correctly

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to read an image and show that image using `OpenCV-2.4.10`. I have read that image several times before and never faced any problem. Now I am trying to read the same image using OpenCV-2.4.10 in VS2010 and for some reasons, the image is not getting read properly.

**Code:**

```
Mat img = imread("D:/image.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat org = img.clone();

std::cout<<"\nChannels: "<<img.channels();
std::cout<<"\Type: "<<img.type();

imshow("GNGGraph1",img);
```

**Code Output:** Channels: 3 Type: 16

**Image:**

[image]

**Imshow (screenshot):**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, you are plotting ``img`` and not ``testImg``? Type 16 is not referring to 16bit, but to 3-channel 8bit. Compare http://ninghang.blogspot.de/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html#!/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html for instance. I would check min/max/mean/sd of the image to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @Phann: yes, I am plotting `img`. Thanks for the clarification about `16` thing but my problem is still there :(

Comment: Type 16 clearly says that it is 8bit, so maybe (for some other weird reason) all values are zero or something similar. Can you read out some values for checking as in my first comment?

Comment: @Phann: I got `min = 0` and `max = 255`

Comment: Seems reasonable. So maybe there is a problem with imshow? I'm using OpenCV3.1 and can read and show the image. Maybe you want to try ``imwrite`` and see if the same error appears there too. Btw: using ``minMaxLoc`` I get a range from 0 to 255. Don't have further tipps at the moment.

Comment: I don't see [`waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey) after that call to `imshow`. From the docs: "This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes care of event processing."

Comment: Would guess missing waitKey(1), too!

Comment: @Micka, @Dan: I did have `cvWaitKey(0)` but after a couple of lines (just before `return 0`). But once I put the `waitKey(0)` next to the `imshow()` line, it WORKED.

Comment: waitKey must be at/before the position where you want to render/display the image.